# Weird Firefox negative margins

Tags: css, firefox, opera, image, margins

I have discovered a strange bug in Firefox 4.0.1 (It also happend in Opera 11.5) so I've created this example to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/whYC7/

If viewed in safari everything looks fine, but when I open it in Firefox or Opera the image inside the div with a negative margin still takes up space in the div underneath.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct rendering per the CSS spec.  The negative margin means that the top of the red div is higher than it would be otherwise, but once you determine where its top is the position of the text just depends on the intersection of the float and the div.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats the paragraph starting "A line box is next to a float".

You may want to file a bug on WebKit here.

Comment: And in fact, a bug has been on file for WebKit since about 5 years ago: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10900

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this issues as well in FF and IE9...an absolute positioned div does not seem to recognize negative margins, though using top:100px instead of margin-top:-100px does seem to work in FF 12 and ie9

Answer (score 0):

A fix that could work in most cases is to make your div's position absolute and then to use top/left/right/bottom to control position